# Disable/hide "End tour" button in Bootstrap Tour

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the `bootstrap-tour` plug-in (http://bootstraptour.com/), I want to disable or hide the default 'End Tour' button on each step except for the very last step.

I tried modifying the step template to get rid of `End Tour` button completely, but how do I activate it on the very last step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the class `.btn-end` to your end button using the template parameter:

   ```
   var tour = new Tour({
       template: "<div class='popover tour'><div class='arrow'></div><h3 class='popover-title'></h3><div class='popover-content'></div><nav class='popover-navigation'><div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button></div><button class='btn btn-default btn-end' data-role='end'>End tour</button></nav></div>"
   });
   ```
2. Set `.btn-end` to be hidden by default, using CSS:
   `.btn-end { display: none; }`
3. Target the last step, using the `#step-x` ID in CSS.  The last step ID will be the number of steps, minus 1 (as the count starts at 0).  If you have 5 steps, the Id will be `#step-4`  (5 - 1 = **4**).
   `#step-4 .btn-end { display: block; }`

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfu5f/2/

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Axel's answer would be to use the data part as the CSS selector:

1. Set the End button to be hidden by default: `.popover-navigation [data-role="end"] { display: none; }`
2. Target the last step using: `#step-4 .popover-navigation [data-role="end"] { display: block; }`

This shortens the amount of steps and if you have a custom popover defined somewhere else, this prevents you from having to recopy that template.